# Can You Rely On NSString intValue Never Raising An Exception

Tags: ios, objective-c

The documentation of NSString does not mention any exceptions being raised when intValue method is called.  I find it a little hard to believe without someone else with Objective-C expertise confirming that no exception will be raised even if the string were say alphanumeric.

(p.s. I have done my tests and no exception is ever raised, the method seems to do its best to convert the string to an int and if all fails returns 0).

Comment: I'm sure you can feed it a corrupted object.  And of course you can do `intValue` on an object that doesn't support that method.

Comment: When you say corrupted object, you mean an object that is not actually an NSString?

Comment: Documentation says: " Returns 0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number." so yes you can rely on it never raising an exception.

Comment: Or an NSString with its internals corrupted somehow.

Comment: If your concern is that your string may contain alpha numeric values then you can scan your string for aplha characters and if you find any then throw an exception yourself and don't call intValue

Comment: I do not want to throw an exception, for my current app the behavior of parsing the int if possible or else using 0 is very appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to suspect a framework method of this kind of behavior. Exceptions [can't be used](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ExceptionHandling.html) for control flow or recoverable errors in Cocoa (Touch). If `intValue` raised an exception for invalid input, you would have to validate your input every time. The validation would be at least significant fraction of the work required for the actual conversion.

`intValue` therefore takes the sensible route of simply returning a documented "failure" value when it can't convert.*

---

*It's not perfect, of course, since the special value is also a valid converted value. If that becomes a problem, though, you can use `NSScanner` or `NSNumberFormatter`.